# Shadowbox + jQuery not working - No errors

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup, shadowbox

First, apologies. I'm a js newb.

I'm attempting to trigger a shadowbox with the load of a specific page - a "pop-up" if you will. Nothing happens and according to firebug, there are no errors to report.

I should note that this is wordpress, so I'm using the default jQuery call and also shadowbox rolled into a WP plug-in. Shadowbox does work properly in other areas of the site, as do jQuery functions.

`noConflict()` is used because WP also loads prototype by default, which conflicts with the jQuery dollar sign.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j(function(){
            //Set cookie
                $j.cookie('padpop_viewed',true);

                    // open a welcome message as soon as the window loads
            $j(function() {
                Shadowbox.open({
                content: '<div width="600" height="460" style="margin:auto;"><a href="<?php  bloginfo('url');?>"/products/"><img src="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/ipad-pop.jpg" width="600" height="460" alt="Redacted"/></a></div>',
                    player: "html",
                height: "470",
                width:  "610"
                });
            });
        });
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as I have spent hours consulting the documentation of each aspect of this.

Thanks, 
S.

Answer (score 2):

You should not nest `$(function() { ... })` calls.

Remove the inner `$j(function() {`.

**EDIT**: and call

```
Shadowbox.init({
    // let's skip the automatic setup because we don't have any
    // properly configured link elements on the page
    skipSetup: true
});
```

Comment: Done. But still not working ... and now Shadowbox is not functioning where it previously had. 

I suspect that the WP plug-in makes the init call by default. I just made sure to put my code underneath the wp_head function.